# Loading recipient URL second time, automatically redirects to returnURL

Tags: docusignapi

So I created an envelope, set the tags where the signatures are supposed to go, and I get the recipient URL for the signer by doing this:

```
Dim xmlBody3 As String = "<recipientViewRequest xmlns=""http://www.docusign.com/restapi"">" &
"<authenticationMethod>email</authenticationMethod>" &
"<editors><canEditRecipientEmails>false</canEditRecipientEmails><canEditRecipientNames>false</canEditRecipientNames></editors>" &
"<email>" & recipientEmail3 & "</email>" &
"<returnUrl>" & returnUrl2 & "</returnUrl>" &
"<clientUserId>100003</clientUserId>" &
"<userName>" & recipientName3 & "</userName>" &
"</recipientViewRequest>"

url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information"
Dim myRequest3 As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = initializeRequest(url, "GET", Nothing, username, password, integratorKey)
Dim myResponse3 As String = getResponseBody(myRequest3)
baseURL = parseDataFromResponse(myResponse3, "baseUrl")
url = baseURL & "/envelopes/" & eid & "/views/recipient"
myRequest3 = initializeRequest(url, "POST", xmlBody3, username, password, integratorKey)
myResponse3 = getResponseBody(myRequest3)
Dim recipientView3 As String = parseDataFromResponse(myResponse3, "url")
```

The first time I load the URL returned at the end here, I get the signing console where I'm prompted to being and click where I want to sign. If I DO NOT sign it ("hit back on browser, close browser, etc) and reload that URL a second time... it doesn't prompt me to sign anymore and immediately directs me to the value of returnUrl. Is the recipientViewRequest URL valid only once? Because even though I never signed it, i can't get back to the signing console.

Answer (score 2):

The URL provided by DocuSign for embedded signing is a one time use only URL. You will need to request a new URL for subsequent access.

https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#Basic%20Scenarios/Embedded%20Signing.htm?Highlight=embedded%20signing

Comment: I understand. So if I re-run the same code above, the response given by Docusign recipient view response SHOULD return a new, unique URL for me, correct?  ... This giving the signer another chance to sign.

Comment: You will absolutely get a new, unique URL which will bring the recipient into the signing ceremony - yes.